# HOW TO MANAGE A GOOD PRIVACY POLICY GENERATOR IN META FOR DEVELOPERS (Change to Live Status)

Tags: android, ios, facebook, app-store

I'm trying for hours to generate a Privacy Policy in Meta for Developers, but I can't achieve a good result, always take a `206` HTTP response in Debugger, and

> The following required properties are missing: of type, of description, fb:app_id.

I don't have a webpage, I only want to test an app.

I want to include login with Facebook in my App, but I have stuck on this problem.

[image: Problem image]

I was trying with ***[www.freeprivacypolicy.com](http://www.freeprivacypolicy.com)*** or similar pages. I want that I can have a Privacy Policy that allows me to change From Development status to Live.

Comment: _"I only want to test an app"_ - you are saying you want to take the app live, so that's more than testing then. So you need a privacy policy, hosted somewhere on the web under a URL that is accessible to Facebook.